# It is possible to establish peer connection between desktop and Android using TCP USB ADB?

Tags: android, adb, webrtc

I would to build app that connects between Android app to computer using usb. 
I have made few steps. I forwarded tcp ports using adb command:

```
adb forward tcp:9500 tcp:9500
```

I created TCP server on Android on host: 127.0.0.1 port: 9500. Then I connected to desktop to the server using TCP client on 127.0.0.1:9500 created on Node.js. At this point everything works, devices connected. In the next step devices started signaling. 
Android generated offer:

```
{"sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 1782695619798442838 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS ARDAMS\r\nm=video 9 UDP\/TLS\/RTP\/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 127\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:Pwou\r\na=ice-pwd:uqEm2PMHFnvFSdkIPgF\/LdCh\r\na=ice-options:trickle renomination\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 52:E4:76:A8:57:37:EB:33:F8:4A:96:D3:D8:3F:FE:A8:F9:3D:7B:8D:E7:9D:AB:A0:C4:83:B9:46:A2:FC:5C:44\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:0\r\na=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:3 http:\/\/www.webrtc.org\/experiments\/rtp-hdrext\/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation\r\na=extmap:5 http:\/\/www.ietf.org\/id\/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=extmap:6 http:\/\/www.webrtc.org\/experiments\/rtp-hdrext\/playout-delay\r\na=extmap:7 http:\/\/www.webrtc.org\/experiments\/rtp-hdrext\/video-content-type\r\na=extmap:8 http:\/\/www.webrtc.org\/experiments\/rtp-hdrext\/video-timing\r\na=extmap:9 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:96 VP8\/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli\r\na=rtpmap:97 rtx\/90000\r\na=fmtp:97 apt=96\r\na=rtpmap:98 VP9\/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli\r\na=rtpmap:99 rtx\/90000\r\na=fmtp:99 apt=98\r\na=rtpmap:100 red\/90000\r\na=rtpmap:101 rtx\/90000\r\na=fmtp:101 apt=100\r\na=rtpmap:127 ulpfec\/90000\r\na=ssrc-group:FID 1916955335 2452582321\r\na=ssrc:1916955335 cname:tw17+zUY4UoZ4dvY\r\na=ssrc:1916955335 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0\r\na=ssrc:1916955335 mslabel:ARDAMS\r\na=ssrc:1916955335 label:ARDAMSv0\r\na=ssrc:2452582321 cname:tw17+zUY4UoZ4dvY\r\na=ssrc:2452582321 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSv0\r\na=ssrc:2452582321 mslabel:ARDAMS\r\na=ssrc:2452582321 label:ARDAMSv0\r\nm=audio 9 UDP\/TLS\/RTP\/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 102 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:Pwou\r\na=ice-pwd:uqEm2PMHFnvFSdkIPgF\/LdCh\r\na=ice-options:trickle renomination\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 52:E4:76:A8:57:37:EB:33:F8:4A:96:D3:D8:3F:FE:A8:F9:3D:7B:8D:E7:9D:AB:A0:C4:83:B9:46:A2:FC:5C:44\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:1\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:9 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSa0\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus\/48000\/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC\/16000\r\na=rtpmap:104 ISAC\/32000\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:102 ILBC\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:106 CN\/32000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN\/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN\/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event\/48000\r\na=rtpmap:112 telephone-event\/32000\r\na=rtpmap:113 telephone-event\/16000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event\/8000\r\na=ssrc:3388490788 cname:tw17+zUY4UoZ4dvY\r\na=ssrc:3388490788 msid:ARDAMS ARDAMSa0\r\na=ssrc:3388490788 mslabel:ARDAMS\r\na=ssrc:3388490788 label:ARDAMSa0\r\nm=application 9 DTLS\/SCTP 5000\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:Pwou\r\na=ice-pwd:uqEm2PMHFnvFSdkIPgF\/LdCh\r\na=ice-options:trickle renomination\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 52:E4:76:A8:57:37:EB:33:F8:4A:96:D3:D8:3F:FE:A8:F9:3D:7B:8D:E7:9D:AB:A0:C4:83:B9:46:A2:FC:5C:44\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:2\r\na=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024\r\n","type":"offer"}
```

Node.js Electron generated answer:

```
{"type":"answer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 3020637264513396082 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0 1 2\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 98 99 100 101 127\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:I5v3\r\na=ice-pwd:r+w1c6kV+e2j7GqRfdZqS+wq\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 AA:CF:6A:FC:DB:C7:E0:63:C8:C8:FE:79:9F:18:5F:A1:79:43:D9:09:91:45:0A:28:7F:EF:4E:9E:40:9A:45:8D\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:0\r\na=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation\r\na=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay\r\na=recvonly\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc\r\na=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:97 apt=96\r\na=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb\r\na=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc\r\na=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:99 apt=98\r\na=rtpmap:100 red/90000\r\na=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000\r\na=fmtp:101 apt=100\r\na=rtpmap:127 ulpfec/90000\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:I5v3\r\na=ice-pwd:r+w1c6kV+e2j7GqRfdZqS+wq\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 AA:CF:6A:FC:DB:C7:E0:63:C8:C8:FE:79:9F:18:5F:A1:79:43:D9:09:91:45:0A:28:7F:EF:4E:9E:40:9A:45:8D\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:1\r\na=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=recvonly\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000\r\na=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:106 CN/32000\r\na=rtpmap:105 CN/16000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\na=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000\r\na=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\nm=application 9 DTLS/SCTP 5000\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\nb=AS:30\r\na=ice-ufrag:I5v3\r\na=ice-pwd:r+w1c6kV+e2j7GqRfdZqS+wq\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 AA:CF:6A:FC:DB:C7:E0:63:C8:C8:FE:79:9F:18:5F:A1:79:43:D9:09:91:45:0A:28:7F:EF:4E:9E:40:9A:45:8D\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:2\r\na=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024\r\n"}
```

Then whole process fail on ICE connection. The sides can't set proper ice candidates. But after connected the devices to the same local wifi network webrtc started gathering new ice candidates and peer connection succeed. I would establish connection using USB TCP/IP way only. 
Can someone point me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to forward UDP and convince the software to generate the correct sdp (or edit it yourself).

Or you can set up a TURN server.

Comment: What are you mean by convince the software to generate the correct sdp? :D